# Printing a MySql results set in java

Tags: java, printing

How can we print the data of a mysql results set on the printer with correct alignments of each data rows and columns? Lets say, we get a dataset from a mysql database and populate that data in to a JTable, out of that JTable is there a way to get a printed hard-copy without any borders and lines of the JTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pad each column with spaces and make it the same length as the column size.

Answer (score 1):

Java has the [System.out.printf](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/0200__printf-Method.htm) method, which works like the printf of C with a format String and varargs.

I think for DB reports it is more convenient on the long run to use a Report Generator like [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/website/ireportwebsite/IR%20Website/index.html?header=project&target=ireport).